# Twig_Error_Loader exception caught when looking for a repository

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xampp, twig

I have to work on a project that my internship supervisor made on windows. He's making the backend and I'm making the frontend, but I need the backend to deal with the frontend of project.

I'm using XAMPP, and my Document Root is in /home/remy/www.

When I put in the URL `localhost/Salto`, it finds it rather easily. However, when I click on the web link that it shows to me, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The
>   "/home/remy/www/Salto\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle/Resources/views"
>   directory does not exist
>   ("/home/remy/www/Salto\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle/Resources/views").

Some other things that are in the filesystem.php in the core and where the error is :

`/home/remy/www/Salto/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 101`.

I was asking myself if it could be with the `\` in Windows (OS of my internship supervisor) and the fact that I'm working on Linux, which prevents me from go into the depths of the back-end.

Comment: Does this directory exist?

Comment: Yes it does ! I can navigate into it

Comment: Have you installed vendors by yourself (with `composer install`) or did you get the project already configured from your supervisor?

Comment: This is him who configured it. But idk why, i think that my problem comes from my Symfony. So i try to install it again, but i have a problem now with my pear, looks like i'm never gonna end with the problems..

Comment: I mean, when i try to create a new project on symfony, my php is literally doing nothing at all :/. And now it seems like pear extension is not possible, while I configured it again on my php.ini.. Don't you have any idea on how to solve this?